# Complexity of INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE operations in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-update, time-complexity, sql-insert, sql-delete

I am trying to implement a like function in my android App.I will be storing the likes for each item displayed in a table named 'likes'. I wonder what is the best way to implement such like and unlike in SQL tables.I can either INSERT row on like and DELETE row on unlike OR I can use a extra column 'liked' which would have value 1 for like and value 0 for unlike and run a SELECT query first to check whether a row with same data exist and UPDATE 'liked' value to 1.If the user have never liked that item,then run a INSERT query to add data and set 'liked' value to 1. On unlike, I could use a UPDATE query to set 'liked' value to 0.

Can anyone suggest me the best way to do my task?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? please tag it

Comment: Shouldn't that be quite simple for you also to test yourself?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question depends on what you want to do with the data.  If all you ever wanted to do was to allow one user to like/unlike an item and to record the total number of likes and unlikes, then you would use `update`.

The `items` table would have a column, called `likes` perhaps.  This would be incremented for a "like" and decremented for an "unlike".

I would argue that this functionality is not sufficient, and you really want to maintain a record of every "like" and "unlike".  This suggests a table, say:

```
create table userLikesItem (
    userLikesItemId int auto_increment primary key,  -- "auto_increment" depends on the database
    userId int references users(userId),
    itemId int references items(itemId),
    like int check (like in (1, -1)),
    createdAt datetime default current_timestamp
);
```

A like/unlike would result in `insert`ing a new row into the table.  Initially, you would aggregate this table to calculate the total number of likes for an item.

When your data gets too big, you would ponder ways to store the summarized results more efficiently, perhaps using triggers or stored procedures.